# Realtime with Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, real-time-updates

I need to add realtime notifications to my Rails app (Rails 3.2, Ruby 1.93, Phusion Passenger). I have another app using Rails 5 that uses Action Cable to deal with realtime notifications and now I'm looking for a similar solution that works with Rails 3.2. Any suggestion on how to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check out [Faye](https://faye.jcoglan.com/), which is like ActionCable, based on pub/sub messaging.

Comment: It's exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!